# What's the sql for this condition?

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all records from `wp_usermeta` with user_id whose meta_value is "tonetone" which is spam accounts.

As you know already, there are many records with one user_id in wp_usermeta.
I tried like this but doesn't work. Thanks to anyone who can show me the way.

```
delete from wp_usermeta where user_id = (select user_id from wp_usermeta where meta_value = "tonetone")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
delete from wp_usermeta where meta_value = "tonetone"
```

Don't you actually mean to delete the rows from wp_users, as opposed to just the metadata?